# junit test case for compar two null object

Tags: java, testing, junit

i am trying to write junit test case,
to compare two field ;on of them comes from db and another from my program. my fields maybe

- both is null
- both is notnull

i use assertEqual for both this state,but when both is null , assertEqual throw nullpointerException,
how can i fix it?

```
assertEquals(String.valueOf(DBnumber),String.valueOf(number) );
```

ps . i must write one test for both situation
ps. i was think i can use assertnull but its void and i cant write condition statement

Comment: `String.valueOf` returns string `"null"` for `null` argument, so how come assertEquals throw NPE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use this Code to fix my junit Test
assertEquals(,String.valueOf(number) );

```
if (isNull(String.valueOf(DBnumber))){
    assertTrue(Validator.isNull(String.valueOf(number)));
}else{
    assertEquals(String.valueOf(DBnumber), String.valueOf(number));
}
```

*isNull is a method ,if input String is null return true , else return false.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the two fields should be equal, but they can either be null or non-null.  This is a job for [StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
assertTrue(StringUtils.equals(DBnumber, number));
```

Comment: yes, you understanding correct thanks:) , i use StringUtils right now but give this error "java.lang.assertionError" , i import org.apache.commons.lang  for StringUtils

Comment: Yep: `org.apache.commons.lang` is the correct import.  If you're getting an `assertionError`, then that means the assertion is failing; that is, `StringUtils.equals(DBnumber, number)` is returning false.

Comment: i cant understand , i write both item before assertTrue, and both is null , then this false what means?

Comment: What class are `DBnumber` and `number`?

Comment: Hm -- are you sure they're both truly null (and not "null", the String?)  If they are, can you try simply `DBnumber == number`?  The following code passes:

    `String s1 = null;`
    `String s2 = null;`
    `assertTrue(s1 == s2);`

Comment: i'm sure i write it in console :null and ->null , i cant use == its risky , its a big project :| , thanks :)